# Is there any way to tag products?

Tags: tag

I want to tag products. I have looked at the [official tag documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tag_overview.htm&language=en_US) and it doesn't look like it but it seems like such an obvious use case I figure I must be missing something. I know I can just set up a simple object with some text and a junction between the two but I would prefer to stick with standard functionality if I could. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sfdcfox pointed out in the comments that SOSL is not case sensitive and some apex code can help with normalization. This is looking like a better solution.

---

A possible solution my coworkers and I brainstormed is to add a text field and use SOSL to query individual tags. <strike>There are a number of issues with this. It relies on people knowing the tags in advanced, otherwise there would be pc, PC, Pc etc. Then there is the problem with people including the delimiting character in the tag itself. Overall, less than ideal.</strike>

Comment: SOSL doesn't have a problem with PC, Pc, pC; they are all equivalent. That aside, a custom list setting plus some Apex Code could help with validation and normalization.